# How can i solve this problem with hot-update

Tags: reactjs, webpack, localhost, create-react-app

After a few days of non-coding I went back and after I try to do something or change
the value of text in component in my app and I did noticed that my localserver is not respoding.

everytime i need to refresh the browser, the console shows it to me --> http://localhost:3000/main.771124e74a556866ffcc.hot-update.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

I create app with (CRA)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/507pF.jpg)

Comment: Hi Fredi, did you restart your server? In the terminal `cd` into the directory of your app and then type: `npm run start`, `npm run` or `yarn start`.

Comment: yes, but it didn't help